# How do I convert a Nokogiri statement into Mechanize for screen scraping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to use Mechanize to scape some tags from a page. I've used Nokogiri successfully to scrape them before, but now I'm trying to combine them into a wider Mechanize class. Here is the Nokogiri statement:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@model.url, "User-Agent" => request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
@model.icons = page.css("link[rel='apple-touch-icon']").to_s
```

And here is what I thought would be the Mechanize equivalent but it's not working:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(@model.url, "User-Agent" => request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
@model.icons = page.search("link[rel='apple-touch-icon']").to_s
```

The first one returns a link tag as expected `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" etc etc..></link>`. The second statement returns a blank string. If I take the `to_s` off the end I get a super long output. I assume it's an error or the actual Mechanize object or something.

Link to long output when not converting to string: https://gist.github.com/eadam/5583541

Comment: Define "not working". What do you get as the return value of the `search` method? What do you expect to get? It would also be helpful if you pointed us to the page or included the appropriate snippet.

Comment: I've update the question with full statements and definition of not working. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the "super long output" you get?

Comment: Please don't put a link to your "long output". *WHEN* that link breaks your question will be pretty useless for others who are looking for the same answer in the future. Instead, summarize what you are linking to if it's truly that long, and provide the link to the complete information. If it's not really that long, append it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample HTML it's difficult to recreate the problem, so this is some general information that might help you.

That "long output" is the `inspect` output of the Nokogiri::NodeSet you got when you used the `search` method. If `search` returns multiple nodes, or the nodes have lots of children, the `inspect` output can go on for a ways, but, that's what it should do.

`css` and `search` are very similar, in that they return a NodeSet. `css` assumes that the string passed in is a CSS accessor, while `search` is more generic, and attempts to figure out whether what was passed in was a CSS or XPath expression. If it figures wrong the odds are bad for the pattern to find a match. You can use `at` or `search` to be generic and let Nokogiri figure it out, or `at_css`, `at_xpath` or `css` and `xpath` to respectively replace them. The `at` derivations all return the first matching Node, similar to using `search('some_path').first`.

`to_s` turns the NodeSet back into a representation of the source that was passed in. I prefer to be more explicit, using either `to_xml`, `to_xhtml` or `to_html`.

Why don't you get output for `search` like you do for `css`? I don't know because I can't test against the HTML you're parsing. Answering questions, like data-processing, is a GIGO situation.